# How can I get the name of a child class?

Tags: python

```
class Foo():

class Bar(Foo):
```

A method of Foo have to know the name of the child class. How can I get the name?

In this example I want to get "Bar".

I'm sorry for my english.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it needs to be an instancemethod:

```
def meth(self): print self.__class__
```

If you want a classmethod:

```
@classmethod
def meth(cls): print cls
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked. This returns the class of the current object not the **child** class as the OP asked.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli That's what he meant.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely old, but since i stumbled upon this by [duckduck'ing](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+name+of+child+class) the topic...

Consider you have:

```py
class Foo():
   pass

class Bar(Foo):
   pass
```

### Python 3

```py
my_bar = Bar()
type(my_bar).__name__
# Bar
```

### Python 2

```py
my_bar = Bar()
my_bar.__class__.__name__
# Bar
```